# What is "top (women's type of clothing) called in Korean?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice

[image]

I would like to know how is "top" (see photo: women's type of clothing for upper part of the body) called in Korean.

I've searched in the dictionary, but the results don't match with what I want.

Dictionary shows me these words, but according to Google Images:

상의 / 윗옷 = any kind of clothes for the upper part of the body

탱크톱 = sleeveless t-shirt

정상 = top of a mountain

So, which is the word for saying "top"?

Comment: In this case, visiting Korean online shopping sites and finding out categories will give you an answer. For example, G마켓 shows only four main categories for women's tops (여성 상의): 티셔츠 (T-shirts), 맨투맨/후드티 (sweatshirts/hoodies), 블라우스 (blouses), and 셔츠 (shirts). Although there are a few gender-specific loanwords for clothes such as 브래지어 (brassières) and 블라우스 (blouses), you will still have to add 여성 (female) or 여성용 (ladies') before some words (e.g. 셔츠) for clothing. Using specific terms, for example 배꼽티 (belly-exposing T-shirts), 탱크톱 (tank tops) and 터틀넥 (turtlenecks), will not be a problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

There may be no exact definition (It depends on site)

민소매 = sleeveness : We cut the cloth at arm hole

브라 탑런닝 : 민소매 hides shoulder but this use thin strings so
that it shows shoulders

브라탑 = 스포츠 브라 : In 브라 탑런닝, we cut out the below of
chest. (In OP's picture, the third)

탱크탑 : In sleeveness, we cut out the middle between chest and the
navel. To me, I call the second 탱크탑.

오프숄더 : We cut out shoulder. Consider the first picture.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! But just one thing, if I would like to say a more general word for any type of top, if simply saying 탑, would I be understood or should I say another word?